# Unable to set progress bar height in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and trying to locate all controlls in the center of a view. Unfortunately, my progress bar is appearing of zero height despite I set `50dp`:

[image]

The code is following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="MYACTIVITY"
    android:id="@+id/activity_MY"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

why?

Comment: Hmm.. kinda odd try to run your app, what is the outcome of your progressBar

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="MYACTIVITY"
    android:id="@+id/activity_MY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

   <Button
       android:text="Button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:id="@+id/button"/>

   <ProgressBar
       style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
       android:layout_above="@+id/button"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:max="100"
       android:progress="50" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to replace `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` to `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

And

Remove `layout_gravity="center"` from parent and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to align button center Vertical

Comment: Why such replacement? :)

Answer (score 0):

**replace** `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"`

**to**      `style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

Comment: Why such replacement?

Comment: These are attributes of the theme that point at themed styles you can use for progress indicators. Their exact values can change from theme to theme, it's just a layer of indirection.